# Тип базового класса в миксинах

Tags: python, типы, include, типизация, mixins

У меня есть большой класс разбитый на миксины:

```py
class MyObject(MyObjectFilesMixin, MyObjectProcessingMixin, ...):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = self.preprocess(value)
```

Миксины такие:

```py
class MyObjectFilesMixin:
    def load_from_file(cls, filename):
        return ...
```

Сейчас хочу добавить везде типизацию:

```py
class MyObjectFilesMixin:
    def load_from_file(cls, filename: str) -> MyObject:
        return ...


class MyObjectProcessingMixin:
    def preprocess(self: MyObject, value: bytes):
        return value  # логика опущена

    def append(self: MyObject, other: MyObject):
        self.value += other.value
```

Но это приводит к циклическим зависимостям. Конечно, можно создать какой-нибудь класс вида `MyObjectBase` (следуя принципу инверсии зависимостей), чтобы главный класс `MyObject` мог наследовать этот базовый, а миксины использовали его как тип аргумента/результата в методах, но это всё же корявый тип будет. Как это можно исправить??

<sub>Немного скучаю по заголовочным/исходным файлам C++</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл способ, как обойтись без дублирования кода, протоколов и т.п, [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)! Решение у меня простое:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Type
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from my_object import MyObject
MO = Type('MyObject')


class MyObjectFilesMixin:
    def load_from_file(cls: MO, filename: str) -> 'MyObject':
        # Now I'm able to access all the methods of MyObject by cls
        # with correct IDE support and MyPy checking
        return ...


class MyObjectProcessingMixin:
    def preprocess(self: 'MyObject', value: bytes):
        return value  # логика опущена

    def append(self: 'MyObject', other: 'MyObject'):
        self.value += other.value
```

Разве что теперь всплывает warning, видимо MyPy не ожидает получить ребёнка как тип у родителя:

> Mypy: The erased type of self "Type[... MyObject]" is not a supertype of its class "Type[...MyObjectFilesMixin]"

Но это малая цена за то, чтобы методы и типы были видны и правильно поняты IDE и MyPy!

Answer (score 0):

у cls и self type hints не используют, так как и так понятно, что self  это экземпляр объекта того класса, который вызывается, а cls это объект класса в котором определен метод данного класса(только не забудьте декоратор @classmethod)

Comment: Окай, но вопрос про типизацию аргументов и результатов методов, которые принимают и возвращают объекты того же класса, вроде приведённых `append` и `load_from_file`.

Comment: возвращай объект того же класса, который передается в экземпляре. Ты же передаешь self как экземпляр объекта класса MyObjectFilesMixin, так его и возвращай

Comment: 1. Тыкать здесь никто не позволял. 2. Так не будет адекватно работать строка `obj = MyObject. load_from_file(...)`, переменная получит неверный тип, другие методы не будут видны MyPy, а если явно указывать тип переменной, то операция присвоения будет кривой.

Comment: Извините, если вас этим обидел. Обычно даже при собеседовании переходишь на ты, хотя первый раз говоришь с человеком. Это признак того что мы в узком кругу друзей разработчиков

Comment: а по вопросу, зачем вообще возвращать объект ? obj = MyObjectProcessingMixin() obj = obj.preprocess()

Comment: Очень смущает запись `obj = MyObjectProcessingMixin()` – миксины не так работают, они ведь создаются для инкапсуляции, наследования и разделения кода, а не для создания экземпляров...

Comment: я тут не про миксин, а про класс вообще, зачем возвращать тот же объект экземпляра класса из которого ты вызываешь метод ?